# ¿Por qué los metodos no estaticos en java no se pueden testear en junit usando blue J?

Tags: java

el problema es que usando java POO necesito hacer algunos test de los métodos que tengo implementado pero deseo saber si alguien me explica claro y breve porque necesitan ser estáticos los métodos y que diferencia tiene que un método sea estático y que no sea estatico

Comment: Método estático: (No se necesita instanciar un objeto de dicha clase para utilizar el método estático, ej : todos los métodos de Math)

Comment: eso resuelve mi duda sobre los metodos estáticos solo me falta el porque deben ser estáticos para poder testearlos con Junit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es relevante si el método es estático o no. Lo que importa es que ante un input conocido, el método pueda devolver un output también conocido y evaluar el resultado (salida) de dicho método. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
//clase a evaluar
public class MiClase {
    public static boolean cadenaVacia(String cadena) {
        return cadena != null && cadena.isEmpty();
    }

    public String capitalizar(String cadena) {
        String resultado = "";
        if (!cadenaVacia(cadena)) {
            resultado = cadena.toUpperCase();
        }
        return resultado;
    }
}

//clase de pruebas unitarias
public class MiClaseTest {
    @Test
    public void pruebaCadenaVacia() {
        String cadena = "";
        assertThat(MiClase.cadenaVacia(cadena), is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void pruebaCapitalizar() {
        MiClase miClase = new MiClase();
        String cadena = "hola";
        assertThat(miClase.capitalizar(cadena), equalTo("HOLA"));
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver, no es relevante si el método bajo prueba unitaria es estático o no. La prueba unitaria se ejecutará sin problemas.

Comment: muchas gracias no se que mas puedo hacer ya te di respuesta correcta gracias a tu ejemplo me di cuenta que realmente estaba haciendo mal mis pruebas yo usaba esto "assertEquals(true,Palindrome.palindrome("anitalavalatina"))"
cuando en realidad primero debia instanciar un objeto " 
Palindrome nuevoObj = new Palindrome();
"assertEquals(true,nuevoObj.palindrome("anitalavalatina"))"
entonces por eso debian ser estaticos mis metodos por mi error claro que voy aprendiendo

Comment: De nada. Estamos para apoyarnos.